# Get $index after filter

Tags: angularjs

I have a small image gallery which has a search box and when the user clicks on a image it'll open a lightbox with that same image.

Basically I'm passing the **$index** to a function which opens the item in **$scope.list[lb.index]**.

my code:

```
HTML
<input type="text" ng-model="query.name" />
<ul class="list" ng-show="list.length>0">
    <li ng-repeat="item in list | filter:query">
        <a class="img" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/uploads/<%item.image%>)'}" ng-click="openLB($index)"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="lightbox" ng-if="lb.show">
    <a class="prev" ng-show="list.length>1" ng-click="changeItemLB(lb.index, 'prev')"></a>
    <a class="next" ng-show="list.length>1" ng-click="changeItemLB(lb.index, 'next')"></a>
    <div class="holder">
        <img ng-if="list[lb.index].image.length" ng-src="/uploads/<%list[lb.index].image%>" />
    </div>
</div>

Angular
$scope.openLB = function(index) {

    $scope.lb.show = true;
    $scope.lb.index = index;

};
$scope.changeItemLB = function(index, action) {

    var tot = $scope.list.length-1,
        goto = 0;

    if(action=='prev') goto = index==0 ? tot : index-1; 
    if(action=='next') goto = index==tot ? 0 : index+1; 

    $scope.openLB(goto);
}
```

The problem is after the user filters the results (search input), the click still maintains the index from the list without the filter which makes the lightbox open the wrong image. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: The way I've worked around this in the past is to pass the actual object to the controller function and use indexOf to find its index in the list. I'm not sure if this is even close to best practice, but it's worked for me.

Comment: ok, gonna try it, thanks

Comment: Yes, pass the object. Not typically a good practice to pass $index (for the very reasons you are experiencing).

Comment: I'm passing the $index because the lightbox has the "previous" and "next" functionality, that's why I thought it was easier to pass the $index

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass object instead of index

Suppose you have 5 item in your list

filter showing two result.

If you click then $index value will be your current view's index

but your list still then have 5 item.

Try like this

```
<a class="img" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/uploads/<%item.image%>)'}" ng-click="openLB(item)"></a>
```

controller

```
$scope.openLB = function(item) {

    var index = $scope.list.indexOf(item);
    $scope.lb.show = true;
    $scope.lb.index = index;

};
```

**EDIT**

How to get Filtered result

Try like this

**view**

```
<li ng-repeat="item in filtered= (list | filter:query)">
```

**controller**

```
$scope.filtered=[];
```

Now you can get yor filtered list from `$scope.filtered`

Comment: It worked, I just have to adjust the previous/next functionality :) thanks

Comment: Is there anyway to get the hole list already filtered, so the lightbox runs the previous and next only on that filtered list?

Comment: The view part solved my issue. When you shared the same $scope.variable for many ng-repeat + filter. You need a unique identifier to differentiate its length based on the filtered result.